# push object into nested array with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

im new to mongodb and im having a problems.
I have a document like this

```
[
    {
    _id: "post1",
    content: "post1 content",
    comments: [
    {
      id: "comment 1",
      user:"user comment",
      replies:[]
    },
    {
      id: "comment 2",
      user:"user comment",
      replies:[]
    }
        ]
    },
{
    _id: "post2",
    content: "post2 content",
    comments: [
    {
      id: "comment 1",
      user:"user comment",
      replies:[]
    },
    {
      id: "comment 2",
      user:"user comment",
      replies:[]
    }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can i put new object into replies?
I got the postid and commentid i need

Answer (score 1):

Use `$elemMatch` operator to match your specific comment in a post, and then push the reply into the `replies` array using `$push`. Like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "post1",
  comments: {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: "comment 1"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$push": {
    "comments.$.replies": {
      "$each": [
        "value1",
        "value2"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the playgrounf [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nm9Mq9tj8_-).

In mongoose it can be achieved like this:

```
await CollectionName.updateOne({
      _id: "post1",
      comments: {
        $elemMatch: {
          id: "comment 1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$push": {
        "comments.$.replies": {
          "$each": [
            "value1",
            "value2"
          ]
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Why code runs on the playground but not in my project? Do you know any reason?

There is no error message, just run but no changes in my document

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using? And what is the exact mongoose query? Please share it, here

Comment: im using mongoose 6.3.4
here is my code

   `await Post.updateOne(
      {
        postId: postId,
        comments: {
          $elemMatch: {
            id: commentId,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $push: {
          "comments.$.replies": {
            $each: [
              {
                id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                user: req.user,
                content: req.body.reply__content,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      }
    )`

Comment: Try this query and check whether it returns anything or not. `await Post.findOne({         postId: postId,  comments: {$elemMatch: { id: commentId}}})`

Comment: Thank you so much for supporting me
That query just return null for some reason

Comment: postId: "jasfhdajsfy89asnsdashnkdjhn"
commentId: "62a6afb452c3c047cbf22762"

`{
  postId: 'jasfhdajsfy89asnsdashnkdjhn',
  comments: [
    {
      id: new ObjectId("62a6afb452c3c047cbf22762"),
      user: [Object],
      content: 'test comment',    
      replies: []
    }
 ]} `

here is my post object
if i remove the `comments:{$elemMatch:{id: commentId}}` then it return the correct post

Comment: Try using as listed in this documentation. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch

Comment: I figured that if i use `$elemMatch:{content: "test comment"}` then it return the correct post

So that means you cant compare the commentId string with the new ObjectId, am i wrong?

Comment: you should convert commentId `string` to `objectId`, if it's of type id in mongodb

Comment: Can i ask one more question?

if my post has a "tags" field, which is an array contains the categories of the post
like tags: [nodejs,react,express]
How can we query a document that it's tags field content the keyword input 
like how can we loop over the array field?
Thanks you again

Comment: There are various query operator for array fields. You can have a look at them here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-array/. Did the conversion of commentId worked? For looping over the array fields, you will have to use an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: It's worked perfectly, dont know why my comment has disappeared

thanks you again